# How to create send telegram bot callback?

Tags: telegram, tdlib

I write some kind of telegram client to communicate with bot and automate some actions.

And I have hard time trying to understsand how to imitate press of button.

I receive message from bot and I get inlineKeyboardButtonTypeCallback instance.

It has data_ field and its description says ( https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1inline_keyboard_button_type_callback.html):

"Data to be sent to the bot via a callback query."

I wonder how should I send callback query ?

I know how to send ordinary message but I guess it is not about sending this data as ordinary telegram message.

I suppose there is some sort of TdApi.Function for that but I can't figure out what exactly.

So question is: what exactly should I deal with "data to be sent to the bot via a callback query." ?